# Jbuttons inside JPanel with background image in right | bottom corner

Tags: java, jbutton

Can somebody explain me how can I put few jButtons  inside jLabel which have background image like on [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6fT8.png) image? The main jFrame is undecorated and is set to full screen.

I saw a lot of different examples like
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165807/put-jbutton-in-bottom-right) or like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905731/how-to-put-component-in-bottom-right-corner-with-gridbaglayout), but these examples are showing only single button in jPanel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd avoid using a `JLabel` for this purpose, it does not calculate it's required size based on it's content, but rather off it's `icon` and `text` properties.

This might be a good or bad thing, but it can catch your unawares if you're not aware of it.

Instead, I'd use a customised `JPanel`, which would allow you to define things like the resize and fill rules, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791984/add-an-background-image-to-a-panel/13792503#13792503) and [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162398/how-to-set-a-background-picture-in-jpanel/22162430#22162430)

Now, once you have that covered, you need to create a panel of your buttons.  I prefer to create a dedicated class, as it makes it easier to isolate functionality and management, but that's me...

```
public class ButtonPane extends JPanel {

    public ButtonPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);

        add(new JButton("Button 1"), gbc);
        add(new JButton("Button 2"), gbc);
        add(new JButton("Button 3"), gbc);
    }

}
```

Next, you need to add this panel to your background

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setContentPane(backgroundPane);
frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.weighty = 1;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
gbc.insets = new Insets(30, 30, 30, 30);

ButtonPane buttonPane = new ButtonPane();
frame.add(buttonPane, gbc);

frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Which can generate something like...

[image: Background image]

Have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for some more details

Comment: @MagProgrammer How would you get rid of that grey background of those buttons. Basically, how could you make the buttons have a transparent background so that that background image is the only thing there behind the buttons.

Comment: It's just a JPanel, you can change the opaque property to make it transparent setOpaque(false)

Answer (score 0):

These examples are truly good enough, I think you should just learn more about swing.
For now, You could simply do:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hi there");
JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
frame.add(b1);
frame.add(b2);
b1.setBounds(60, 60, 40, 40);
b2.setBounds(10, 10, 40, 40);
frame.setVisible(true);         //in case, add frame.setLayout(null);
```

You can of course add buttons to JPanel instead of JFrame